# Guardar entidades anidadas, relación Uno a Muchos, Muchos a Muchos - Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo las siguientes clases:

```
public class OrdenCompra
{
    public int OrdenCompraId { get; set; }
    public int CompañiaId { get; set; }
    public int  Folio { get; set; }
    public int ProyectoId { get; set; }
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Compañia Compañia { get; set; }
    public virtual Proyecto Proyecto { get; set; }
    public virtual Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrdenCompraDetalle> OrdenDeCompraDetalle { get; set; }
}
public class OrdenCompraDetalle
{
    public int OrdenCompraDetalleId { get; set; }
    public int OrdenCompraId { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public virtual OrdenCompra OrdenCompra { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProgramacionSemanal> ProgramacionesSemanales { get; set; }
}
public class ProgramacionSemanal
{
    public int ProgramacionSemanalId { get; set; }
    public int Semana { get; set; }
    public int Manzana { get; set; }
    public int Lote { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaProgramacion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrdenCompraDetalle> OrdenesDeCompraDetalles { get; set; }
}
```

Como se puede ver, `OrdenCompra` (orden de compra) se relaciona con `OrdenCompraDetalle` (detalle) en una **relación Uno a Muchos**, `OrdenCompraDetalle` se relaciona con `ProgramacionSemanal` (programación) en una **relación Muchos a Muchos**.

Este es el diagrama de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otra parte, estoy intentado generar una  con sus *detalles* y con sus respectivas *programaciones* relacionadas a sus *detalles*. El método que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
public new void Create(OrdenCompra entity)
{
    using (var context = new XxxxContext())
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        foreach (var ordenCompraDetalle in entity.OrdenDeCompraDetalle)
        {
            context.Entry(ordenCompraDetalle).State = EntityState.Added;
            foreach (var programacionSemanal in ordenCompraDetalle.ProgramacionesSemanales)
            {
                context.Entry(programacionSemanal).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Me guarda perfectamente la *orden de compra* y los *detalles*, pero el lado de las *programaciones* me crea tantos registros como entidades de *programaciones* lleve el *detalle*.

Por ejemplo:

Una *orden de compra* lleva 2 *detalles*, y cada *detalle* lleva 3 *programaciones*. El método anterior me crea *una* *programación* y 2 *detalles*, pero me inserta 6 *programaciones*.

Requiero que me cree la *orden de compra* y los *detalles*, pero solo me relaciona las *programaciones* a los *detalles*, puesto que estas *programaciones*, ya están creadas previamente.

Comment: @sstan, una ayuda para este hermano de México

Comment: @PedroÁvila: Las menciones sólo disparan notificiones en ciertos casos. Los detalles en http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-respuestas-en-los-comentarios

Comment: ¿Estás usando Entity Framework Core?

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla es imaginar tu modelo como una **matrioskak**. Solo piensa que hay una caja dentro de otra, y mandas a persistir la que contiene a las demás, es decir:

Si tienes un objeto de **tipo A** que a su vez tiene una colección de objetos de **tipo B**, solo debes crear el objeto de **tipo A** como lo haces solo con la programación orientada a objetos, y luego mandas a persistir al objeto de **tipo A**, y listo, él solo se encarga de crear las tuplas en todas las tablas y acomodar las llaves foráneas.

Te sugiero que leas acerca de **FirstCode** en **Entity Framework**.

En tu ejemplo manda a persistir directamente la orden de compra que es la que estás recibiendo.